# Return only the expanded part of a bash glob

Tags: bash, shell-script

Suppose my directory contains the files hesa1.c and hesa2.c. The following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
for j in hes*.c
do
echo $j
done
```

returns hesa1.c and hesa2.c .

How do I get this bash script to return only a1 and a2 (i.e what the wildcard expands to be)?

Answer (score 5):

This isn’t a fully generic answer, as in “show me only the wildcard expansion”, but you can use the shell’s [parameter expansion features](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove the fixed parts of your glob:

```
j=${j#hes}
echo ${j%.c}
```

This removes the fixed “hes” at the start of `j`, then the fixed “.c” at the end of `j`.

Answer (score 1):

[Stephen's shell-based approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528913/22222) is probably the simplest, but you could also use something like `sed`:

```
for j in hes*.c
do
    printf '%s\n' "$j" | sed -E 's/^hes(.*)\.c$/\1/'
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach you can do using `printf` and slice the array:

```
for f in hes*; do printf '%s\n' "${f[@]:3:-2}"; done
```

Also using PE:

```
for f in hes*; do tmp="${f%.c}"; printf '%s\n' "${tmp:3}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a single `*` is present we can write a Perl script `expandstar` to expand it

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $a=shift;                               ## a='he*.c'  for example
my $b=($a=~s/\*/(.*)/gr);                  ## b='he(.*).c'
for( glob($a)){                            ## for all files matching a
   print s/$b/$1/r ,"\n"                   ##   print after substituting
}
```

Usage:

```
$ expandstar 'he*.c'                       ## dont forget '...'
sa1
sa2
```

If you prefer onliners (shame on you):

```
perl -E '$a=$b=shift; $b=~s/\*/(.*)/; say s/$b/$1/r for glob($a)' 'he*.c'
```